# What is the correct way to explicitly use a casting operator in a derived class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

This works fine, `Derive` automatically gets access to `Base`'s operators

```
class Base
{
public:
 operator const SomeType &() const {...}
...
};

class Derive : public Base
{
...
};
```

But I need to add another casting operator to `Base`, which will hide the superclass operator. However when I try to use `using` to resolve this, before adding any new methods, the conversion no longer works at compile-time.

```
class Derive : public Base
{
public:
  using Base::operator const SomeType &;
...
};
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What happens at compile time? What error?

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough information to be answered correctly, please elaborate.

Comment: I mean when I pass a `Derive` to a function/method expecting `SomeType`, the compiler spits an error "cannot convert parameter 1 from `Derive` to `SomeType`"

Comment: Please, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Visual studio 2005 is ancient enough that it could have problems with code that's supposed to work.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/262f08a4cc2bbe94) is a working sample.

Comment: It was a genuine language question not a "what is wrong with my code" question. If what I posted _is_ correct C++, that's the answer to my question and it means something context-specific is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, what I was trying to do *is* correct. Problems were elsewhere in the code.